# Error while executing the statement in cmd - cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Tags: ibm-cloud

Getting the below error while trying to execute the statement in command prompt.

```
C:\users\Blue mix> cf API https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Setting API endpoint to https://api.ng.bluemix.net...
Request error: Get https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/info: http: error connecting to
 proxy http://my.proxyserver.com:8080: dial tcp : lookup my.proxy server.com: GET Address inflow : No such host is known.
TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the HTTPS_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.
FAILED
```

Can you please suggest how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you done as it asked? Is it relevant to your setup?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have configured the https_proxy variable? https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html.

The error message suggests that the hostname you have set for your proxy server can not be resolved to an IP address.

---

**Update:**

You can verify if your machine is able to resolve the hostname of the proxy server by pinging your proxyserver, e.g.

```
C:\> ping my.proxyserver.com
```

Ping will report if it is unable to resolve the proxy hostname to an ip address.  E.g.

```
C:\> ping my.proxyserver.com
Ping request could not find host my.proxyserver.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

If it is unable to resolve to an ip address, you need to fix that problem first.  See here for some tips: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/